# Border around chart teechart

Tags: java, android, teechart

I made a chart with Steema TeeChart, the chart is done, but when it is drawn in the layout there is a border around the layout that it's made by the chart, is not inside the chart, i've used getwalls.setVisible(false) but that is useful only on the axes, how can I remove this border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the BevelOuter. You can deactivate it with this:

```
tChart1.getPanel().setBevelOuter(BevelStyle.NONE);
```